# [RAILS]: redirect_to special path after sign-up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, path, registration

I there, 
I developp a rails app and I have a problem on displaying a special path after sign-up.
I have an attribute :status for my user which is filled in in my sign-up form. If this attribute is checked (true), I would like to display payout_method_path , whereas it is false I want to redirect to root_path.
I have the following error:
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in RegistrationsController#create

Here is my code.
Thks for help...:-)

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

```
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
if current_user.status?
    redirect_to payout_method_path
      flash[:notice] = "Your account is verified before being a seller"
else
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

end

Comment: Add a `return` statement after your redirects specified in your `after_sign_up_path_for` function. Also your flash should be set before the redirect.

Comment: Thks #cannon_Moyer that works

Comment: Anytime. I just posted a answer detailing my original comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the default redirects from being called in devise, you will need to add a return statement in your function like so:

```
 def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     if current_user.status?
         flash[:notice] = "Your account is verified before being a seller"
         redirect_to payout_method_path
     else
         redirect_to root_path
     end
     return
 end
```

This logic would apply to any application where you had a possibility of chaining redirects.

For example (wrong way):

```
def my_function
     if true == true
         redirect_to different_path
     end
     redirect_to root_path
end
```

The above function would fail. However, adding a return after the redirect (shown below) would cause the function to halt and prevent the execution of the other redirect.

Example (right way):

```
def my_function
     if true == true
         redirect_to different_path
         return
     end
     redirect_to root_path
end
```